# Java String#contains() using String#matches() with escape character

Tags: java, regex, string, contains

I need a simple way to implement the `contains` function using `matches`. I believe this is my starting point:

```
xxx.matches("'.*yyy.*'");
```

But I need to make it a universal method and pre-process whatever I search for to be accepted by matches! This must be done using only the escape '\' character!

Imagine a string `SEARCH_FOR` that can contain some special characters that must be "regex escaped"...

```
String SEARCH_FOR="*.\\"
xxx.matches("'.*" + SEARCH_FOR + ".*'");
```

Are there any catches? Special situations? Any other "special chars should be taken into account?

Comment: Why not just use the proper method call?

Comment: Does surrounding SEARCH_FOR with \Q and \E work for you? They tell the matcher engine to not interpret specials in a certain region.

Comment: @jackrabbit: Wouldn't help if the search string contains \E.

Comment: Doh, did not think about that. pilaster's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: Can't use \Q \E sequences... only \ character! I must "escape" all the special characters.

Comment: @marcolopes: If this isn't homework, then whoever told you to do that manually is a freaking idiot.  There's a function specially made to escape regex special chars; why can't you use it?

Comment: Because of this! QUERY: code.toLowerCase().matches('.*\q.\e.*'), org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Invalid character escape: '\q' !!!

Comment: @marco: (1) "\q" is not "\Q".  The former is not a valid escape sequence, in a regex or anywhere else i'm aware of.  Quit that.  (2) I assume you're trying to add them yourself, rather than simply using `Pattern.quote()` as suggested (or you wouldn't have had that problem). Don't. Trust the function to do its job.

Comment: @marco: (3) If you want case insensitive, stick a `(?i)` at the front of the regex.  Don't do the convert-everything-to-lowercase thing -- besides being wasteful (it creates a String you'll never use again), it also messes up with some character sets / locales.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for [`Pattern.quote(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) ?

This escapes special characters for you.

---

EDIT:

After reading the comments, I really hope you try `Pattern.quote(yourString.toLowerCase())` as it sounds like you've been using Pattern.quote(yourString).toLowerCase(). If DataNucleus is applying the regex then there should be no problems with using the `\Q` and `\E` escape sequence.

Since you have really asked for it, `".\\".replaceAll("(\\.|\\$|\\+|\\*|\\\\)", "\\\\\$1")` outputs `\.\\`
This will escape `.'s`, `$'s`, + `'s`, `*'s` and `\'s`. Note that the security of this is now all upon you. If you don't escape something you needed to, or you escape it incorrectly, you will either allow people to use regex inside the search term when you weren't expecting to or it won't returns results that you were expecting.

Comment: @marco: It basically takes the string you give it, and generates a regex that will match that string.  However it does it, whatever it has to insert.  Might be a backslash, might be brackets, whatever.  All you really need to care about is that it works.  :)

Comment: I have a reason! org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Invalid character escape: '\q'

Comment: @marco: You have broken code elsewhere, is what you have.  `Pattern.quote()` wouldn't give you a regex with `\q` in it.  Either you're forcing the string to lowercase after regexifying it (read: your code is broken) or whatever you're passing it to is (read: datanucleus is broken).  I'm gonna assume its your code.

Comment: I'm converting the result to Lowercase... and that's a bug in my code, but either way, Pattern.quote("*.\\") results in "\Q*.\\E" !! Just saw the Pattern.quote code, and it does exactly that! I need something in the form of "\*\.\\"...

Comment: Don't forget, what you see displayed is not what you'd have to type in.  If you were to type in "\Q.\\E" as a string literal, it'd look like `"\\Q.\\\\E"`.  (There's two levels of escape sequences going on...Java's standard escaping, and then the escape stuff that regexes do.)

Comment: @pimaster: Re: your new regex -- you can safely escape any punctuation character (and in many cases, must; brackets, parens, braces, etc need it too).  Replacing `([^\w\s])` with `\\$1` seems the safer bet.